# Преобразовать в массив

Tags: php

Есть такие входные данные:

```
$key = "level1[level2][level3]";
$val = ["foo", "bar"];
```

Нужно, используя ключ, преобразовать в такой вид:

```
$result = [
    "level1" => [
        "level2" => [
            "level3" => ["foo", "bar"]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Как это сделать? Может быть есть какая-то встроенная или библиотечная функция?

Comment: функции такой нет, но на стеке огромадное кол-во вопросов про это

Comment: вот тут посмотрите мой столетний назад ответ. Формат другой, но смысл тот же - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37659231/4804629

Answer (score 2):

Готовой функции нет, явно нужно писать самому. Если прямо вот под такие условия, то примерно вот так.

```php
<?php
$key = "level1[level2][level3]";
$val = ["foo", "bar"];

function apply( $matches, $val ) {
 $result = [];
 if ( is_array( $matches ) && count( $matches ) > 0 ) {
     $key = $matches[0][0];
     array_shift( $matches );
     $result[$key] = apply( $matches, $val );
 } else { $result = $val; }
 return $result;   
}
if ( preg_match_all("/(\S+?)\[(\S+)\]\[(\S+)\]/", $key, $matches) && is_array($matches) && count($matches) > 1 ) {
   array_shift( $matches );
   $result = apply( $matches, $val );
}
var_dump( $result );
```

Результат

> array(1) {'level1' => array(1) { 'level2' => array(1) {'level3' => array(2) {[0] =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      string(3) "foo", [1] => string(3) "bar" } } } }

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо phpBear. Но я сделал более простое решение:

```
$key = "level1[level2][level3]";
$val = ["foo", "bar"];

parse_str($key, $res);
array_walk_recursive($res, function (&$child) use ($val) {
    if ($child === "") {
        $child = $val;
    }
}, $val);

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Ваше даже элегантнее :)

Comment: Спасибо @phpBear, я через ваш `array_shift` пришел к варианту `array_walk_recursive`.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```
function makeArray($key, $val){
    $result = [];
    $path = explode('[', str_replace("]", "", $key));


    $res = &$result;
    foreach($path as $p){
        $res[$p] = [];
        $res = &$res[$p];
    }
    $res = $val;
    
    return $result;
}
```